# ES2015 import в NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Можно ли, на данный момент, использовать данную фичу ES2015 в NodeJS без использования транспайлеров Babel или Traceur?

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя. Они ещё не готовы в V8 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1569

Answer (score 1):

```
node --es_staging
```

или

```
node --harmony
```

Вопрос только возникает зачем это нужно в node... Но это уже Вам решать как этим пользоваться.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую как только доберусь до ноутбука. А чем такие новые возможности плохи, по Вашему мнению?

Comment: Я не говорю, что они плохи, просто в Node.js сам по себе строится на модульном программировании.

`var module = require("./module/_core.js")`

Comment: @Eugene Если хотите писать библиотеку, то все, кто не пользуется ES6, пользоваться ею не смогут.

Comment: Ну да если так, то это все синтаксический сахар.

Comment: @Pleshevskiy то, что вы описали, то же, что и `import "./module/_core" as module`.

Comment: @D-side почему же? При учете использования версии ноды от 4 очень даже смогут. Никто не запрещает писать свой код без фич ES6.

Comment: @D-side, если так, тогда супер

Comment: @Eugene для запуска придётся запускать ноду в режиме ES6 даже тем, кому ES6 не сдался. Но это всё отговорки, надо пересаживаться на новые версии.

Comment: @D-side в одном из проектов уже начал использовать yield+bluebird coroutine вместо уже ставшей привычной promise chain. Потому и решил поинтересоваться о import/export фичах ES6. Ждём ES7 и async/await

Comment: Попробовал запустить с флагами --es_staging и/или --harmony с node v4.4.3 , но увы не успешно.

Comment: Также не получится переопределить зарезервированные слова, а также нет возможности создать какие-то кастомные инфиксные функции в javascript'e, придумать там свою систему импортов подобную. Так что остается только ждать